# Выражение "белая горячка"

Tags: фразеология

Почему психоз на почве пьянства называют "белой горячкой"? Почему — белая и почему — горячка (я, конечно, не специалист, но не слышал, чтобы у пьяных поднималась температура)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых. Белая горячка (алкогольный делирий) никогда не наблюдаются у пьяных. Это состояние при выходе из запоя, наблюдаемое у алгоголигов "со стажем".

Во-вторых. Алкогольный делирий возникает на II—III стадии алкоголизма, в период прекращения пьянства. Выражается бредом, который обусловлен зрительными, слуховыми и/или тактильными галлюцинациями, **ознобом и повышением температуры**. 
(Вики, курсив мой - b-s)

Почему "белая" сказать наверняка не могу, вроде бы может наблюдаться побледнение кожных покровов.

Answer (score 0):

Почему "горячка", автор предыдущего ответа пояснил верно: бред и буйство больного очень похожи на горячечное состояние. А "белая", наверное потому, что "белое вино", "беленькая" (водка) - причина болезни.

Answer (score -1):

Белая горячка потому, что от воспаления мозга, умопомрачение. А мозг по древнеегипетски изображается идеограммой "яйцо", то есть "белок". Ещё белка- мысь-мысль в "слове о полку Игореве", "Боян бо вещей, если кому хотяше песнь творити, то растекашется мысию (мыслью) по древу...". Белка, хотя и рыжая, но пишется как беля, белка, белок - это случайно указывает на белый цвет.
А водка не всегда белая. её иногда в русских деревнях называют серой или вино в отличии от самогона.